# How to clear error \.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d3ed6a1aa148d5e7a86094c67053f11c\core-1.7.0\res\values

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Resource Linking Failed. I am stuck on the above error for days. It automatically opens values.xml at this line when I click on the error in the build output

Values.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="ColorStateListItem">
        <!-- Base color for this state. -->
        <attr name="android:color"/>
        <!-- Alpha multiplier applied to the base color. -->
        <attr format="float" name="alpha"/>
        <attr name="android:alpha"/>
        <!-- Perceptual luminance applied to the base color. From 0 to 100. -->
        <attr format="float" name="lStar"/>
        <attr name="android:lStar"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

I've checked through every layout file and made sure there are no errors highlighted, have cleaned and tried to rebuild project, have invalidated caches and restarted, i've also tried deleting caches folder in gradle folder under users in local disk C. Inside Android studio I have also tried deleting build folder in app. Nothing seems to work. Kindly help.